# boost.asio spawn call handler directly from current stack

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

My application use boost.asio to run network related tasks that yield (coroutines).

On some occasions when my task is spawned from another spawned task, it's being called directly from the current task's callstack.

I would expect that it'll be queued and may run after the current task get suspended (if no other tasks are pending on the same io_context)

looking at the spawn code, it reaches `boost::asio::dispatch` which trigger async operation

```
  return async_initiate<NullaryToken, void()>(
      detail::initiate_dispatch(), token);
```

So it seems odd that my task has been called directly and not from some dispatcher, is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: It feels like this question indicates that you're probably [still focusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77167534/85371) too much on undocumented implementation details. In this case, QOI room for optimization. If executors did not have this room for optimization, Asio would strictly be too slow for serious server applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asio::dispatch` is documented to dispatch on an executor.

The [`Executor` concept documents](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Executor1.html) the behaviour for `dispatch` as:

> *Effects*: Creates an object f1 initialized with `DECAY_COPY(forward<Func>(f))` ([C++Std [`thread.decaycopy`]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library/decay-copy)) in the current thread of execution . Calls `f1()` at most once. ***The executor may block forward progress of the caller until `f1()` finishes execution***.

(***emphasis*** mine).

Contrast this with `post` or `defer`:

> The executor shall not block forward progress of the caller pending completion of `f1()`

Simply put: `dispatch` MAY execute the handler immediately but only if the currently executing executor implements this optimization and is compatible with the associated executor.

See also for background/examples:

- [What is the difference between post and dispatch from boost::asio when overloads with executor parameter are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76581761/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-dispatch-from-boostasio-when-overloads/76584453#76584453)
- [`strand::running_in_this_thread()` false positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76348933/strandrunning-in-this-thread-false-positive/76353683#76353683)